# ASP.NET Identity not signing in when added to Blazor application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side application, and am trying to add Identity to it. I have added the models, users, roles, etc, and am now trying to write the log-in page. I copied this verbatim from another site where it works fine (only showing the C# code, as the Razor markup doesn't add anything)...

```cs
namespace MyWebSite.Web.Areas.Account.Pages {
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public class LoginModel : PageModel {
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<User> signInManager) =>
      _signInManager = signInManager;

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    public string Jim { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel {
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
      [EmailAddress]
      public string Email { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
      [DataType(DataType.Password)]
      public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public void OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null) {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage)) {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
      }
      returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
      ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

      Jim = $"Signed in: {_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User)}";

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null) {
      returnUrl = $"~/{returnUrl}";
      if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result 
          = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded) {
          return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut) {
          return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt");
        return Page();
      }
      return Page();
    }
  }
}
```

On this new site, the code runs fine, and if I put a breakpoint in the `OnPostAsync` method, I can see that the call to `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` works fine, and the sign-in succeeds. I can also see the cookies being set in the browser dev tools.

However, if I reload the login page, the extra bit of code I added to check if the user is signed in (on the last line of `OnGetAsync()`, where it sets the `Jim` variable that I display in the Razor), I can see that I'm not actually logged in. Also, wherever I've used the Blazor `AuthorizeView` component, I only ever see the bits in the `NotAuthorized` section, not the bits in `Authorized`.

I've double-checked the code between the two sites, and I can't see any reason why this one doesn't work. Both are using .NET 5.

In case it's relevant, `Startup.cs` contains the following (irrelevant bits snipped for clarity)...

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
      services.AddRazorPages();
      services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
      services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
        options.LoginPath = "/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
      });
      services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<User>>();
    }

    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToAreaPage("/_Host", "General");
      });
    }
```

The `RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider` class was picked up [from here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/ProjectTemplates/Web.ProjectTemplates/content/BlazorServerWeb-CSharp/Areas/Identity/RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider.cs).

Anyone any ideas why the log-in isn't working? Please let me know if there is anything more I need to add to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following two lines to your `Configure` method...

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Try that and see if it helps.